# value not getting from div

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="form-row">
<div class="label-column"> Date of Expire</div>
<div class="ctrl-column" data-bind="text: DateofExpire">Feb 23, 2014</div>
</div>
```

we want to collect the Expire date (Feb 23, 2014) from that above Html

my xpath

```
WebElement expDate = driver.findElement(By
            .xpath("//div[contains(@data-bind,'text:DateofExpire')]")).getText();
```

but while executing its produce empty, xpath was perfectly working and only getText() method not returning the value

please suggest to collect the date value

Comment: you missed space `@data-bind,'text:DateofExpire'`..

Comment: Sorry i'm not getting the value String renewalDate = driver.findElement(
    By.xpath("//div[contains(@data-bind,'text: DateofExpire')]"))
    .getText();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (space was missing):

```
//div[contains(@data-bind,'text: DateofExpire')]
```

Comment: do you have a default namespace? e.g., `xmnls="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`? If you have it, you must register that namespace.